# Real time sign language translator with mediapipe

Tags: python, machine-learning, mediapipe

So, i'm making a sign language translator with mediapipe, and it works fine till i hold up both of my hands, it gives the following error: "X has 84 features, but RandomForestClassifier is expecting 42 features as input". I've tried tons of different solutions but none of them have worked so far.
This is the code i'm running:

```
import pickle
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import numpy as np

model_dict = pickle.load(open('./model.p', 'rb'))
model = model_dict['model']

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

mp_hands = mp.solutions.hands
mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
mp_drawing_styles = mp.solutions.drawing_styles

hands = mp_hands.Hands(static_image_mode=True, min_detection_confidence=0.3)

labels_dict = {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'D', 4: 'E', 5: 'F', 6: 'G', 7: 'H', 8: 'I', 9: 'J', 10: 'K', 11: 'L',
               12: 'M', 13: 'N', 14: 'O', 15: 'P', 16: 'Q', 17: 'R', 18: 'S', 19: 'T', 20: 'U', 21: 'V', 22: 'W',
               23: 'X', 24: 'Y', 25: 'Z', 26: 'Middelvinger', 27: 'Dikke vette duim'}

current_char = "niks"  # Initialiseer current_char buiten de loop

while True:
    try:
        # Initialiseer lege lijsten en coördinaten
        data_aux = []
        x_ = []
        y_ = []

        # Lees een frame van de webcam
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        # Haal de hoogte, breedte en kanalen van het frame op
        H, W, _ = frame.shape

        # Converteer het frame naar RGB-formaat
        frame_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

        # Verwerk de handen in het frame met behulp van MediaPipe Hands
        results = hands.process(frame_rgb)

        # Controleer of handen zijn gedetecteerd in het frame
        if results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            # Loop over alle gedetecteerde handen in het frame
            for hand_landmarks in results.multi_hand_landmarks:
                # Teken de landmarks en verbindingslijnen op het frame
                mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(
                    frame,  # afbeelding om op te tekenen
                    hand_landmarks,  # model output
                    mp_hands.HAND_CONNECTIONS,  # verbindingslijnen
                    mp_drawing_styles.get_default_hand_landmarks_style(),
                    mp_drawing_styles.get_default_hand_connections_style())

            # Loop over alle gedetecteerde handen in het frame
            for hand_landmarks in results.multi_hand_landmarks:
                # Loop over alle landmarks (puntcoördinaten) van de hand
                for i in range(len(hand_landmarks.landmark)):
                    x = hand_landmarks.landmark[i].x
                    y = hand_landmarks.landmark[i].y

                    # Voeg de x- en y-coördinaten toe aan de respectievelijke lijsten
                    x_.append(x)
                    y_.append(y)

                # Normaliseer de coördinaten door de minimale x- en y-waarden af te trekken
                for i in range(len(hand_landmarks.landmark)):
                    x = hand_landmarks.landmark[i].x
                    y = hand_landmarks.landmark[i].y
                    data_aux.append(x - min(x_))
                    data_aux.append(y - min(y_))

            # Bereken de positie om een tekstvenster te plaatsen
            x1 = int(min(x_) * W) - 10
            y1 = int(min(y_) * H) - 10

            # Voorspel het karakter met behulp van het getrainde model
            prediction = model.predict([np.asarray(data_aux)])
            predicted_character = labels_dict[int(prediction[0])]

            # Haal de waarschijnlijkheid van de voorspelling op
            prob = model.predict_proba([np.asarray(data_aux)])
            accuracy_percentage = max(prob[0]) * 100

            # Toon het voorspelde karakter en de nauwkeurigheid in de linkerbovenhoek
            cv2.putText(frame, f"{predicted_character} {accuracy_percentage:.2f}%", (10, 30),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 0, 0), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)

            # Controleer of het karakter is veranderd
            if predicted_character != current_char:
                print(f"{accuracy_percentage:.2f}% zekerheid dat het {predicted_character} is")
                current_char = predicted_character

        # Toon het frame met de getekende handen en voorspellingen
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        cv2.waitKey(1)`your text`

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Fout code: {e}")

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Any of you guys have any idea on how to fix my problem?
Thanks in advance

I tried a lot of different solutions but none of them worked so far. i'm expecting the program to be able to scan and translate both of my hands at the same time

Comment: Some sample inputs would be helpful; Some that works and some tha% creates the error.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue, this is because your randomForestClassifier is trained to take 42 features (one hand) inputs, you can write conditional to avoid it, in my case if two hands are on screen the data isn't passed to model. something like below.

```
        # Bereken de positie om een tekstvenster te plaatsen
        x1 = int(min(x_) * W) - 10
        y1 = int(min(y_) * H) - 10

        # Voorspel het karakter met behulp van het getrainde model
        if len(data_aux==42):
            prediction = model.predict([np.asarray(data_aux)])
            predicted_character = labels_dict[int(prediction[0])]

            # Haal de waarschijnlijkheid van de voorspelling op
            prob = model.predict_proba([np.asarray(data_aux)])
            accuracy_percentage = max(prob[0]) * 100
```

This is just to give you some idea, adjust the code accordingly.